# How can I make a Test, which tests if the String has an uppercase, lowercase, special char?

Tags: java, maven, testing

This is my Flaw class

```
enum Flaw {
    NOUPPER( 'U', "No UPPER case letter" ),
    NOLOWER( 'l', "No lower case letter" ),
    NODIGIT( '8', "No digit" ),
    NOSPECIAL( '#', "No special character" ),
    TOO_SHORT( 's', "Too short" );
    final char encoding;
    final String description;

    Flaw( char encoding, String description ) {
        this.encoding = encoding;
        this.description = description;
    }

    char getEncoding() {
        return encoding;
    }

    String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    static Flaw encodingToFlaw( char encoding ) {
        for ( validator.Flaw flaw : values() ) {
            if ( flaw.getEncoding() == encoding ) {
                return flaw;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Collect the encoded flaws into an initially empty set.
     * @param encoding the flaws
     * @return the set of flaws matching the encoding.
     */
    static EnumSet<Flaw> stringToFlawSet( String encoding ) {
        return encoding.chars()
                .mapToObj( c -> Flaw.encodingToFlaw( (char) c ) )
                .filter( f -> f != null )
                .collect( toCollection( () -> noneOf( Flaw.class ) ) );
    }
```

And this is my Test class, I need to work in a TDM style and I cannot find the right approach on my assignments. I hope you can help me to understand what kind of approach I should take and also to understand how to test correctly

```
 @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({
        "'password', 'U|8|#|s|l'",
       // "'I AM A UPPERCASE PASSWORD', 'uppercase'",
       // "'I am a good password with 1 digit', 'digit'",
       // "'I am a perfect Password #69', 'special'"
    })
    void invalidPassword(String password, String miss){
        String [] missArray = miss.split("//|");
        
        EnumSet<Flaw> flaws = EnumSet.allOf( Flaw.class );
       
        SoftAssertions.assertSoftly(softly -> {
            softly.assertThat(password)
                    .hasSizeGreaterThan(9);
            
                    
        });
```

Comment: The `char` type is obsolete, unable to represent most of the characters defined in Unicode. Use code point integer numbers instead.

Comment: Could you please explain what `TDM` stands for?

Comment: TDM stands for Test Driven Development